# Display default record when query dont have any rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to display a default record in a simple query but my attempt doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
     COALESCE(suppliers.supplier_name, 'No records') AS supplier_name
FROM suppliers
    LEFT JOIN suppliers_purchases USING(supplier_id)
    LEFT JOIN suppliers_purchases_articles USING(supplierpurchase_id)
WHERE suppliers_purchases_articles.article_id = 150
ORDER BY suppliers_purchases.supplierpurchase_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

As the query returns no rows the `coalesce` never kicks in - there's no value to act on, let alone `NULL`.

While technically it is possible to solve your problem in SQL, it would become an awfully large, ugly, unmaintainable piece of SQL. This is because you are trying to solve an issue in SQL that it was never meant to do - a display problem. SQL is meant to control absolute and strict data sets, not default to informational messages based on the lack of a result set. `No records` is not the name of any supplier in your database, so don't list it as one.

Long story short: don't solve presentational issues in your data layer. Your front end code should handle the lack of results and fall back to properly displaying `No records` instead, where it's localizable, controllable, and expected by the developer after you.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree this is a presentation logic issue, I have come across times where I had to control it from the database as I couldn't alter the UI.

If that is the case, you have a couple different options.  One of them is to introduce a new temporary table and use another `outer join`:

```
SELECT 
     COALESCE(suppliers.supplier_name, 'No records') AS supplier_name
FROM (SELECT 1 as FakeCol) t 
    LEFT JOIN suppliers ON suppliers_purchases_articles.article_id = 150
    LEFT JOIN suppliers_purchases USING(supplier_id)
    LEFT JOIN suppliers_purchases_articles USING(supplierpurchase_id)
ORDER BY suppliers_purchases.supplierpurchase_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

- [Condensed Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80025/3)

Note I've moved the `where` criteria to the `join`. This isn't completely necessary, I just prefer the way it reads as such.  If you have to leave `where` criteria, you don't want to negate your `outer join`, so you'll need to add corresponding `is null` checks as well.